# Bound on the difference of matrix diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two diagonal matrices $\Lambda,\hat{\Lambda}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with non-negative diagonal elements. And I have two matrices $W,\hat{W}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with $m\geq n$, each with orthogonal columns, $W^TW=\hat{W}^T\hat{W}=I$ (the $n\times n$ identity matrix). I also have the following quantities bounded:
$$
\| \text{diag}(\Lambda) - \text{diag}(\hat{\Lambda}) \|_\infty \leq a,
$$ 
where $\text{diag}(\cdot)$ means the diagonal elements and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and
$$
\| WW^T - \hat{W}\hat{W}^T \|_{M,2} \leq b,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{M,2}$ is the matrix 2-norm. Note this last inequality is a statement about the distance between the subspace spanned by the columns of $W$ and the subspace spanned by the columns of $\hat{W}$. I want to bound
$$
\|\text{diag}(W\Lambda W^T) - \text{diag}(\hat{W}\hat{\Lambda}\hat{W}^T)\|_\infty
$$
in terms of $a$ and $b$. I'm actively working on this, so I'll keep the post updated.

**UPDATE 1**

Here's what I got so far. To make the notation a little simpler, define
$$
\alpha = \text{diag}(W\Lambda W^T), \quad \lambda = \text{diag}(\Lambda), \quad U = W\circ W,
$$
where $\circ$ means Hadamard (or element-wise) product. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\alpha - \hat{\alpha}\|_\infty 
&= \|U\lambda - \hat{U}\hat{\lambda}\|_\infty\\
&\leq \|(U-\hat{U})\lambda\|_\infty + \|\hat{U}(\lambda-\hat{\lambda})\|_\infty\\
&\leq \|U-\hat{U}\|_\infty\|\lambda\|_\infty + \|\hat{U}\|_\infty\|\lambda-\hat{\lambda}\|_\infty\\
&\leq \|U-\hat{U}\|_\infty\lambda_1 + a.
\end{aligned}
$$
The last line follows because the maximum row sum of $\hat{U}$ is less than 1. Now I just need to bound 
$$
\|U - \hat{U}\|_\infty \;=\;
\|W\circ W - \hat{W}\circ\hat{W}\|_\infty
\;=\; \|(W-\hat{W})\circ (W+\hat{W})\|_\infty
$$
in terms of 
$$
\|WW^T - \hat{W}\hat{W}^T\|_2.
$$
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foiled again by counterexamples! Pete Stewart's well-cited SIREV paper [Error and perturbation bounds for subspaces associated with certain eigenvalue problems](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1015095) has two nearby matrices in the introduction whose eigenvectors are very different, but the subspaces generated by the eigenvectors are very close. So I don't think it's possible to show
$$
\|W\circ W - \hat{W}\circ\hat{W}\|_\infty \leq C\|WW^T -\hat{W}\hat{W}^T\|_2,
$$
in general. Like the recent NYTimes profile of Terry Tao says, "The steady state of mathematical research is to be completely stuck."